# How to learn if a value is even or odd in bash?

Tags: bash, rounding, median

I am building a movie database and I need to find a median for ratings. 
I'm really new to bash (it's my first assignment).

I wrote:

```
let evencheck=$"(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)%2)"
if [ $evencheck==0 ] 
then
let median="(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)/2)"
else
let median="(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)/2)+1"
fi
```

When `$amount_of_movies = 6` and `$amount_of_0_movies = 1`. I would expect median to be 3.  but it's 2.  Why is that?

Comment: Tag the question is homework please.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# != 1 )) ; then
    echo "syntax:  `basename $0` number"
    exit 255
else
    _value=$(expr $1 % 2)
    (( $_value == 0 )) && exit 1 || exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let evencheck="(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)%2)"
if [ $evencheck -eq 0  ] 
then
   let median="(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)/2)"
else
   let median="(($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)/2)+1"
fi
```

Removing the $, and then testing for numeric equality.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your if test:

```
[ "$evencheck" == 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does median have some sort of default value? The way I see it, it's not even going inside the if.

```
(6-1) % 2
5 % 2
1, not 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't parse. To evaluate expressions in Bash, you say

```
let evencheck="$((($Amount_of_movies-$Amount_of_0_movies)%2))"
```

That is, evaluate arithmetics like so: `$(( ... ))`

That said, your problem is in the conditional. See `man test`.

```
if [ $evencheck = 0 ]; then
```

You have to wrap the equality sign with whitespace on both sides. Use a single equality sign.

Answer (score 0):

The outermost parentheses and none of the quotes are necessary in what you've got (they may be in other circumstances). Also, in a `let` statement you can omit the dollar sign from variable names.

```
let evencheck=(Amount_of_movies-Amount_of_0_movies)%2
if [ $evencheck == 0 ]  
then
    let median=(Amount_of_movies-Amount_of_0_movies)/2
else
    let median=(Amount_of_movies-Amount_of_0_movies)/2+1
fi
```

If you use the `(())` form instead of `let`, you can uses spaces to make your formulas more readable. You can also use them in `if` statements:

```
(( evencheck = ( Amount_of_movies - Amount_of_0_movies ) % 2 ))
if (( evencheck == 0 ))
then
    (( median = ( Amount_of_movies - Amount_of_0_movies ) / 2 ))
else
    (( median = ( Amount_of_movies - Amount_of_0_movies ) / 2 + 1 ))
fi
```